# Proving two sequences overlap

Tags: sequences-and-series, invariance

$A =a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_{25}$, strictly increasing with each term being non-negative integer and striclty less than 50

$B=a_1+2,a_2+2\dots,a_{25}+2$ with same condition as last except that $50\equiv0$ and $51\equiv1$. So B is not necessarily strictly increasing for the last 2 terms.

How to prove that they overlap? i.e. atleast one number appears in both of them ?